# Problems with regex java

Tags: java, regex, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am working a java project and have hit a wall. I am trying to read in a file and create some objects with that file. A line will create an object of type TransportLine, followed by n lines that will create stations to populate the TransportLine data structure, before adding the TransportLine to the TransportSystem, n times. Here is a sample input:

```
TransportLine RD
Shady Grove;2100
Rockville;7800
Farragut North;1600
Metro Center;1200
Gallery Place;2400
Union Station;5300
Fort Totten;2050
Takoma;4800
Glenmont;0
TransportLine OR
Vienna;1100
East Falls Church;3100
Rosslyn;2730
Foggy Bottom;1600
Metro Center;3300
Smithsonian;2400
LEnfant Plaza;2000
Potomac Ave;5200
Stadium Armony;7200
New Carlton;0
TransportLine GR
GreenBelt;1100;
College Park;4100
Fort Tottem;3400
Columbia Heights;6200
Gallery Place;2700
LEnfant Plaza;5500
Anacostia;6240
Branch Ave;0
```

And here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    TransportSystem ts = new TransportSystem();
    String LINE = "TransportLine";

    Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("WashingtonDCMetro.txt"));
    String str;
    String lineID, name;
    int distance;

    while(read.hasNext()){
        str = read.nextLine();
        List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s"));
        TransportLine temp = new TransportLine(items.get(1));
        System.out.println(items.toString());
        while(read.hasNext("\\p{ASCII}*;\\p{ASCII}*")){
            str = read.nextLine();
            items = Arrays.asList(str.split(";"));
            System.out.println(items.toString());
            temp.addStation(new Station(items.get(0), temp.getLineID(), Integer.parseInt(items.get(1))));
        }
        ts.addLine(temp);
    }

    System.out.println(ts.toString());
}
```

The problem seems to lie in the nested while loop:

```
while(read.hasNext("\\p{ASCII}*;\\p{ASCII}*")){
```

I want to check the next line for any number of characters or whitespace followed by ";" followed by any number of digits, except it's not picking up on the second line of the input due to the space:

```
Shady Grove;2100
```

The first time this loop is stepped into is the third line of input. Any ideas how to modify the regex to catch the lines that aren't preceeded by TransportLine? ( I think i may have answered my own question here, off to try something, but help still very much appreciated... I am scratching my head )

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex,

```
\w+( \w+)*;\d+
```

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ5uQ1/2)

It will capture all lines except lines containing the string `TransportLine`